# How to implement Django SSO with custom user model and object permission (EX/django-guardian) in multiple projects

Tags: python, django, django-guardian

I tried to search and study some information on the google, but I couldn't find the good solution.

I have several Django projects and want to create "Member" project store user information which implement Single-Sign-On(SSO) feature (ex/"[django-simple-sso](https://github.com/divio/django-simple-sso)"). Then I need to classify user permission, I study the package "[django-guardian](https://github.com/django-guardian/django-guardian)" which maybe can help me do object permission.

I do below things to create custom model in "Member" project. Then I just post the code that I add/change.

```py
# setting.py of "Member" project

INSTALLED_APPS = [    
    'users',
    'guardian'
]

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'guardian.backends.ObjectPermissionBackend',
)
```

I add an app which called users in the project named "Member".

```py
# admin.py in the users app of Member project.

from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from .forms import CustomUserCreationForm, CustomUserChangeForm
from .models import CustomUser

class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    add_form = CustomUserCreationForm
    form = CustomUserChangeForm
    model = CustomUser
    list_display = ('email', 'is_staff', 'is_active', 'employee_account', 'location', 'chinese_name', 'english_name', 'extension', 'last_login', 'date_joined')
    list_filter = ('email', 'is_staff', 'is_active', 'employee_account', 'location', 'chinese_name', 'english_name', 'extension', 'last_login', 'date_joined')
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('employee_account', 'password')}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields': ('is_staff', 'is_active')}),
    )
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('employee_account', 'password1', 'password2', 'is_staff', 'is_active')}
        ),
    )
    search_fields = ('employee_account',)
    ordering = ('employee_account',)

admin.site.register(CustomUser, CustomUserAdmin)
```

```py
# apps.py in the users app of Member project.  

from django.apps import AppConfig

class UsersConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'users'
```

```py
# forms.py in the users app of Member project.

from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm
from .models import CustomUser

class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta(UserCreationForm):
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('employee_account',)


class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('employee_account',)
```

```py
# manager.py in the users app of Member project.

from django.contrib.auth.base_user import BaseUserManager
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _


class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    """
    Custom user model manager where email is the unique identifiers
    for authentication instead of usernames.
    """
    def create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Create and save a User with the given email and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError(_('The Email must be set'))
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Create and save a SuperUser with the given email and password.
        """
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError(_('Superuser must have is_staff=True.'))
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError(_('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.'))
        return self.create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)
```

```py
# models.py in the users app of Member project

from django.db import models
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser
from django.contrib.auth.models import PermissionsMixin
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from django.utils import timezone
from .managers import CustomUserManager


class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    employee_account = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    chinese_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    english_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    extension = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=125)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'employee_account'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['location','chinese_name','english_name','extension', 'email']

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.employee_account
```

Then I use django shell to add user and assign permission.

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import  Group

>>> from users.models import CustomUser

>>> jack = CustomUser.objects.create_user('123456789@gamil.com', '123456789')

>>> admins = Group.objects.create(name='admins')

>>> jack.has_perm('change_group', admins)
False

>>> from guardian.models import UserObjectPermission

>>> UserObjectPermission.objects.assign_perm('change_group', jack, obj=admins)

<UserObjectPermission: admins |  | change_group>

>>> jack.has_perm('change_group', admins)
True

>>> jack.has_perm('change_group')
False
```

After that I create an book app in another project named book_web.

```
# model.py in the book app of book_web project

from django.db import models

class Book(models.Model):

    sn = models.CharField(max_length=200) 
    book = models.CharField(max_length=100) 
    author = models.CharField(max_length=100) 
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    number = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
```

#### 1. It seems work abnormally when key this command `UserObjectPermission.objects.assign_perm('change_group', jack, obj=admins)`. I found that response doesn't show the user name which is different with [django-guardian](https://github.com/django-guardian/django-guardian#usage) example code.

#### 2. I don't know how to assign Book object permission in Member project such as django-guardian example code. Because there is not same model as Book model in the Member project.

Does anyone have similar experience about this?

If you have another recommendation package to implement the feature, welcome to share your experience. Thanks for your response.

Comment: If there is code to share that gives insight into the matter or you use specific code examples please do mention in your question. Now your question its too broad.

Comment: @ZF007 
Thanks for the reminder. I add some example code to express my problem clearly.